# LeafLet Draw, Marker Layer can't be Clicked

Tags: javascript, maps, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I'm using Leaflet 1.0.1 with LeafLet Draw, but the problem is Marker Layer can't be clicked with the LeafLet stable version

https://jsfiddle.net/tb0pct68/2/

```
var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            osmAttrib = '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
            osm = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, {maxZoom: 18, attribution: osmAttrib});


        map = new L.Map('map', {center: new L.LatLng(51.505, -0.04), zoom: 13}),
        drawnItems = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);



        L.control.layers({
         //'osm':osm.addTo(map),
         "google": osm.addTo(map),
        }, {/*'drawlayer':drawnItems*/}, { position: 'topleft', collapsed: false }).addTo(map);
        map.addControl(new L.Control.Draw({
            edit: {
                featureGroup: drawnItems,
                poly : {
                    allowIntersection : false
                }
            },
            draw: {
                polygon : {
                    allowIntersection: false,
                    showArea:true
                }
            }
        }));

   function layerClick(e) {

            alert('yes its clicked');
        }

        map.on('draw:created', function(event) {
            var layer = event.layer;

      layer.on('click',layerClick);

            drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
        });
```

Draw a rectangle, it will show alert Dailog but Marker layer click is not working, not sure what is the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

According to this [open issue on Github](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/issues/602), the leaflet draw plugin supports only leaflet 0.7.x. It is only a matter of time before it gets fixed though (I hope!).